# Connected select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I'm have several select tags on one page, grouped 3 by 3.
And I want every group by 3 to share the same option list, where if the user chooses "Sweden" in the first box, then "Sweden" is removed  from the options of the second box. But here is the tricky part, IF the user decides to change the first box again to lets say "England", then "Sweden" will be back in the list of the second select box. Sounds fuzzy?
My code manages to remove a country from the next box but then it is removed for good, also the change is only affecting the closest Select tag right now. I would like to change the content for all 4 select tags in that group.
Here is my code, please point me in the right direction:

```
<div id="group1">
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="group2">
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="England">England</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


$("select").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('div').next('div').find("option").removeClass('hide');
   $(this).closest('div').next('div').find("option[value='"+value+"']").addClass('hide');
});
```

UPDATED:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duo7qs2u/2/)

Comment: Tried to do some logic. Find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/duo7qs2u/3/). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Akshay thanks, that is something to work with at least, it will keep me occupied for a will, trying out new things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one class in your css

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

after that update your script function

```
$(this).closest('div').next('div').find("option").removeClass('hide');
       $(this).closest('div').next('div').find("option[value='"+value+"']").addClass('hide');
```

In your code , you remove the element from the DOM using `.remove()`
if you need that element again you save that element in DOM.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Nice! That is a good start, definitely helps with the remove part, but not one question is still left, if the user chooses "England" in the first box and "Sweden" in the next box, the last box should have removed both.. :/